# Replace a list of words with one unique word in R

Tags: r, regex, nlp, data-cleaning, topic-modeling

I am working on a text analysis with R and have a dataset (text corpus) with various sentences about different fruits. For example: "**apple**", "**banana**" , "**orange**", "**pear**", etc.

Since it is not relevant for the analysis whether someone writes about "apples" or "bananas", I want to replace all different fruits with one specific word, for example "**allfruits**".

I thought about using regex but I am facing two issues;

1) I want to avoid separate code lines for each kind of fruit. Thus, is there a way to define a list or a vector that I can use so that the function replaces **all words** in that list (apple, bananas, pear, etc.) with one specific word "**allfruits**"?

2) I want to avoid that words that are *NOT* a fruit but contain the same string as a fruit (e.g. the word "appletini) get replaced by the function.

Example: 
If I have a sentence that says: "***Apple*** is my favourite fruit, **appletini** is my favourite drink. I also like **bananas**!"
I want following to happen: ***allfruits*** is my favourite fruit, appletini is my favourite drink. I also like **allfruits**!

I am not sure whether it is possible to write this with a gsub function. Thus, all help is much appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`allfruits` can be extended to contain any words to be replaced:

```
allfruits = c("apple", "banana" , "orange", "pear")
replacement = "allfruits"
text = "Apple is my favourite fruit, appletini is my favourite drink. I also like bananas!"

gsub(paste0("\\b(", paste0(allfruits, collapse="|"), ")[s]?\\b"), replacement, text, ignore.case = TRUE)
```

Returns

```
[1] "allfruits is my favourite fruit, appletini is my favourite drink. I also like allfruits!"
```

The regex:

- `\\b` - wordboundary
- `(", paste0(allfruits, collapse="|"), ")` - all fruits names separated by a `|` (or)
- `s?` - optional letter 's'
- `\\b` - wordboundary
- `ignore.case = TRUE` - ignore case

Comment: Thank you so much! This really helped to solve the issue. I am new to the whole gsub and regex functions topic, so it is still a bit confusing, especially the part about the "wordboundaries".

Do you have an example of how I would write the regex if I wanted to replace a specific string within a word - for example to replace "apple" within the word "appletini" and  make "allfruitstini" out of it?. Same goes for an example if the word apple was in between two strings (like: "stringapplestring" becomes "stringallfruitsstring")

Comment: Removing the wordboundary part in the example above would do what you ask in the comment. In the descripion of the `pattern` argument in `?gsub`  we find a link to R's regex documentation. There we find the different expressions we can use. You could then start with a teststring and try different patterns.

Answer (score 0):

```
str <- "Apple is my favourite fruit, appletini is my favourite drink. I also like bananas!"
gsub("(\\bapples?\\b)|(\\bbananas?\\b)", "allfruits", str, ignore.case = T)
```

- `\\b` means *boundary*, that is the end of a word (punctuation, space, nothing after...)
- `|` means *OR*
- `()` defines a *group*
- `s?` means with a `s` if possible